# How to get a WPF XAML element using the string value of it's Name

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a huge number of programmatically generated XAML elements where I have the string value of their x:Name value. Here is a very simplistic example of an element that is generated:

```
NameScope.SetNameScope(_container, new NameScope());
Label _label = new Label {
    Name = "label_" + index.ToString(), 
    Content = "some value",
};
_container.Children.Add(_label);
_container.RegisterName(_label.Name, _label);
```

Here is how I am trying to access the element:

```
var _node = this.FindName("label_" + index.ToString());
if (_node != null && _node is Label) {
    Label _element = _node as Label;
    _element.Content = "another value";
}else{
    // always comes back null for all elements
}
```

For context I am attempting to access the element object to make a small change to different properties without having to rewrite the whole app using some other method of generating the UI elements or binding. In this example I am changing a simple field of content, but in the actual app there are lots of properties that need to be changed.

Anyone have any suggestions on how can I access the element using the string name?

Comment: The code you are showing should work (assuming that you call FindName on the same root element where you added the Labels before), it could however be simplified to `if (node is Label label) { label.Content = ... }`. Besides that, it may be the perfect occasion to rewrite your application so that it uses an ItemsControl.

Comment: @Clemens , If the binding has already been created (evaluated) and after that x:Name will be changed (replaced, added), will the binding be re-evaluated?
I'm not sure, but I think the naming should happen before the first evaluation of the binding.